# vmware vcenter use evaluation version to ugrade

Tags: vmware-vsphere, update, vmware-vcenter, upgrade

I have a rather pressing issues that I need to resolve as soon as possible, and in order to do it I need to upgrade my current installation of vCenter 5.5 to 5.5Update3.

The problem is I cannot get the vCenter iso downloaded, because my vm account does not allow it.

So, my question is: if I was do download the evaluation version of the software and then simply apply the licence keys I have, will that work? I cannot remember if that is possible or not from the licensing point of view.

All your input on this matter is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's possible... Or just sign up for another evaluation to get yourself a 60-day trial to do what you need.